# Unifi's command not found with the paramiko's shell

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I would like to send SSH commands to Unifi antennas, specifically the following command: `set-inform http://unifi.<ip>:<port>/inform`. This command is fully functional with Putty but when I use the following code, I get this response:

```
Resp: 
Err: ash: set-inform: not found
```

I suspect an error with the selected shell.

```
import paramiko

ip = 'XX.XX.XX.XX'
port = 22
username = 'XXX'
password = 'XXX'
try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, port, username, password)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("set-inform http://unifi.<ip>:<port>/inform")
    outlines = stdout.readlines()
    errors = stderr.readlines()
    resp = ''.join(outlines)
    respErrors = ''.join(errors)
    print('Resp: '+resp)
    print('Err: '+respErrors)# Output
except AttributeError:
    print("Erreur inconnue" + stderr)
except TimeoutError:
    print("Erreur de connexion")
```

Comment: Use the full path to the `set-inform` command so your shell can find it. In order to find the full path, use Putty to run `which set-inform`.

Comment: The command `which set-inform` returns nothing to me :( . This is a specific command from Unifi

Comment: Ok, try `type set-inform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to specify the path to the command. Here is what to write:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(" /usr/bin/mca-cli-op set-inform http://unifi.<ip>:<port>/inform")
```

You can see the entire project here: https://github.com/simbarras/unifiAdopter

Comment: Cool, well done. Thank you for sharing back with the Stack Overflow community. You can accept your own answer and grab the points.